# Distance between two points in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Im working on an excel VBA homework. It's actually a game of a player and a monster. We use arrows to move inside the worksheet and we keep moving and the monster keeps approaching us and we have to try to move away from the monster. But moving to another cell in each step, we need to show the distance between the player and the monster. We need to use the distance formula. I was wondering, since the cell row and cell column is changing everytime, how do I use the distance formula.

Note: we're only using A1 to T23 in the whole worksheet
      some of the cells are coloured which means the player nor the monster can go to these          coloured cells.

We're only beginners so the formula shouldn't be complicated. E.g. use fuctions/for loops

Comment: What is your unit of distance? Number of rows/columns?

Comment: Yes the player/monster can only move from one cell to the next at each time

Answer (score 1):

A basic attempt I hope it would work:

```
Function distance(ya As Double, xa As Double, yb As Double, xb As Double)

distancePoint = Sqr((ya - yb) ^ 2 + (xa - xb) ^ 2)

End Function
```

Comment: To add onto this, your xa and xb values will be the column # of the player and monster, and ya and yb will be the row # of the player and monster. This is the basic distance formula (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance#Geometry)

Comment: u know the position of monster and also the position of player at every point in the game, then its easy to find the distance if you know the distance formula

Comment: I know till this part. The thing I don't get is what is ya,xa,yb and xb for all the cells. I mean once the player moves then all these ya,xa,yb and xb would change too. Im looking for an automatic formula for xA yA xB and yB.

Comment: No I guess its correct for your question. I would like to elaborate that in my formula I have xa & xb as players coordinates and then ya & yb as monsters coordinates and distancePoint is the distance u asked for

Comment: https://course.cse.ust.hk/comp1022q/hkust/s2020_labs/06/player_win.mp4

Comment: This is the video of the whole game, can you access it?

Comment: the link is asking for authentication details

Comment: can you find the coordinates of player and monster at any time in the game?

Comment: Say the player is at cell (12,2) at first and the monster is at (12,19) but then after moving the player is at cell (11, 8) and monster is at (8,17). How would you write the whole formula from the very beginning?

Comment: its actually a course website, sorry bout that

Comment: now the xa, xb, yx & yb has changed from 12, 2, 12, 19 to 11, 8, 8, 17. so distancePoint changed you need to calculate for the new coordinates.

Comment: In the demo video they showed, the excel automatically calculates the distance every time the position of the monster or player changes. What VBA code should I write? Because the area where we can move is big, so we can move from one cell to another randomly and so can the monster

Comment: its sort of like calculating the distance between the activecell and the cell which the monster is in. But note that the activecell changes everytime since we (the player) is  always moving

Comment: there are three cases: 1. when only row changes, 2. when only column changes, and 3. when both column and row changes.

Comment: So what are the 3 VBA codes I need to write?

Comment: also how do you just refer to a cell's row and not column/value?

Comment: @Aysha - `Range.Row` and `Range.Column`, vs. `Range.Value`?